# App version code for beta and production on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

After beta tests on the play console, I have put my app in production. The closed test version and the production version are the same. The play console did not say something like "you can't do this" and after a few days, my app has been accepted and in the play console. Now it is indicated that my app is "available for all user on Google play" but on Google play it is beta version and the installation button is not there.
According to Google help support, the version code for production should be higher than the one of closed test and I can't understand why.
Does someone have experienced the same issue ?